# IntelliJ with Spring boot: cannot find symbol GetMapping and RequestParam

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm following the Spring tutorial on the JetBrains [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/your-first-spring-application.html) and when I try to build and run after adding the `sayHello()` method, it tells me it cannot find symbol `RequestParam` and `GetMapping`:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "myName", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
```

Error message:

```
Error:(14, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestParam
  location: class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
Error:(13, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GetMapping
  location: class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

Comment: import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
Are you adding these imports in your file ?

Comment: Wow i am dumb. thank you

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to import the annotations. Silly me

Comment: Just did the same thing, demonstrating my reliance on my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included spring-starter-web dependency?? If yes try to import those dependencies sometimes it is not imported by default you need to build project or click on import dependencies in IntelliJ.